How can i get filePath from Gallery image Flutter?
i have just save an image by using : https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver
final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
    Uint8List.fromList(pngBytes),
    quality: 100,
    name: "image_${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpg",
  );
  print(result);
  // encode face
  final filePath = result['filePath'] ?? result['fileUri'];
  print("start endcode");
  if (filePath != null) {
    await ApiService().faceEncoding(filePath);
    if (context.mounted) Navigator.pop(context, "Success");
  } else {
    print('Error: Unable to retrieve file path');
  }

There is log :
ilePath: content://media/external/images/media/354, errorMessage: null, isSuccess: true}
I/flutter (12559): start endcode
I/flutter (12559): Error saving image: PathNotFoundException: Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'content://media/external/images/media/354' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

i can save image but cannot take it's filePath

You said "but cannot take it's filePath", but looking at your log you already got the path returned from ImageGallerySaver, which is content://media/external/images/media/354.
